# How do I delete the content of a text / Log file until the first occurrence occurrence of the keyword using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

How do I delete all the above lines **up to a keyword** (first occurrence) present in a text/log file using PowerShell script?

For example, the content of the log file is:

```
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-23.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-24.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-25.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-26.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-27.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-28.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-29.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-30.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-10-31.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-01.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-02.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-03.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-04.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-05.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-01.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-02.txt
```

I choose Keyword as "**2019-11-01.txt**"

And I wanted to remove all the lines/content present **before** that keyword.
So the remaining text in the same file is:

```
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-01.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-02.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-03.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-04.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-05.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-01.txt
Removing file: localhost_access_log.2019-11-02.txt
```

I tried with some PowerShell scripts like the one given below and it is not meeting its objective. It's only removing the lines in which the keyword is present.

```
$content = Get-Content $file
#$keyword = "2019-11-01.txt"
$content = $content.Where({ $_ -like $keyword }, 'SkipUntil') |
           Set-Content $file -Force
```

Comment: `{ $_ -like $keyword }` -> `{ $_ -like "*${keyword}*" }`. Without the wildcard characters the `-like` operator does the same as the `-eq` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$logFile = 'C:\inet\logfiles\mylog.log'
$pattern = '*2019-11-01.txt*'
$match   = $false

$fileHandle     = [System.IO.File]::Create( $logFile + '.tmp' )

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines( $logFile )) {
    if( $line -like $pattern ) {
        $match = $true
    }
    if( $match ) {
        $line += [environment]::NewLine
        $fileHandle.Write([byte[]][char[]]$line, 0, $line.Length )

    }
}

[void]$fileHandle.Close()

Move-Item -Path $logFile -Destination ($logFile + '.bak')     # backup of old logfile
Move-Item -Path ( $logFile + '.tmp' ) -Destination $logFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as below ... you can get all lines after first occurrence of your keyword

```
$Pattern="2019-11-01"
$filePath="Path to your file with extension"
$fileData=Get-Content $filePath
$startIndex=($fileData|Select-String -Pattern $Pattern)[0].LineNumber - 1
$lastIndex=$fileData.Count - 1
$fileData|Select-Object -Index($startIndex..$lastIndex)|Set-Content $filePath
```

Comment: it works a gem.. THANKS A LOT.
But sometime it throws two exceptions which are given below.

Comment: The exceptions details are given below:
**Cannot index into a null array.**
**Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.**

But I tried to reproduce the exact scenarios but really unable to get that again. 
I believe that it is due to the blank line in the log file.

Also the second file path exception due to the improper placing of " $file = $_ " in the code segment.

Comment: According to the exception, $filePath variable might left blank.

Comment: This solution works well but if the pattern not fount,  it is throwing an exception saying " Cannot index into a null array. " and exiting. 
How to avoid this execution loop being exiting.

In my real application I need to pickup multiple files and continue the checking irrespective of one file not matching the pattern.

Comment: @JohnJustus, You can add a pre-check to identify that file has that pattern or not. add an if condition before selecting the $startIndex : `if($fileData|Select-String -Pattern $Pattern){//your code}`

Comment: `if($fileData|Select-String -Pattern $Pattern){$startIndex=($fileData|Select-String -Pattern $Pattern)[0].LineNumber - 1
$lastIndex=$fileData.Count - 1
$fileData|Select-Object -Index($startIndex..$lastIndex)|Set-Content $filePath}` _sorry for the incorrect formatting_

Comment: Thank you so much... It works well.
 
BTW one general question how can we define/fetch the first line of one file? 
I mean index 0? in powershell script. 
Now I am fetching it by explicitly defining it as start index=0. is that the right way. Can you please share your email please. I dont disturb you but we can have share information. Thanks

Comment: Yes that is the right way, you can also use `-TotalCount` in `Get-Content` command to specify how much lines you want to read from the file. Also I request you to Mark my post as Answer if it is helpful for you.  you can share you email ID I will ping you over there.

Comment: johnjustus74@gmail.com
Kindly mention that your identity. Usually i received so-many job postings at all and I usually neglect those emails.

Of Course it is very much helpful , why such a question? It serves its purpose of this question posted. .

Comment: I marked it as the answer. But received a message saying less than 15 reputation are only recorded but not posted. Sorry friend.